# Errors Compiling

Tags: j#

```
private void Form1_Date (Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
System.TimeDate Date = System.DateTime.Get_Today();
}
```

I have errors compiling which do not specifically state the actual  problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.DateTime Date = System.DateTime.Get_Today();
```